# How to monitor where my connections go?

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I run some tomcat application, use jndi connection pool.
In some time connection pool stops to give connections and application hangs.
Seems because some code receives connection and doesn't return it back to the pool.
How can I monitor - which code does it ? 
More common - I want to see what all connections do at the moment.

I cannot change application. But I can adjust Tomcat, maybe add some interceptors.

Comment: Well I tend to cleverly apply the code searching features of Eclipse to figure out all the pieces of code that fetch a connection, and then I investigate each and every one. Usually the trouble is in bad error handling, like not closing the connection in a finally clause.

Comment: This is not suitable, the codebase is very great, uses lots of aspects and frameworks. Suppose trivial code search will not help.

Comment: Yes, large code bases require lots of effort. That's just a fact.

Comment: Most connection pool implementations can monitor this for you. If you can update the configuration of the pool, you can set parameters that log "abandoned connections" or "expired leases". E.g. for Tomcat's JDBC connection pool, search for "Abandoned" on [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) page.

Comment: Thanks, @vanOekel, that is what I search for !!! If you add separate answer - I mark it as write solution.

Comment: I added an answer. I was not sure you could change the connection pool configuration, but it seems you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most connection pool implementations can be configured to detect connections that are not returned to the pool. E.g. for Tomcat's JDBC connection pool there are various configurations options for "abandoned connections" (connections for which the lease expired). If you search for "Abandoned" on [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) web-page, you'll find the options:

- removeAbandoned
- removeAbandonedTimeout
- logAbandoned
- suspectTimeout

As mentioned on the web-page, these settings will add a little overhead but at least your application will not hang. When testing your application, set a low value for `removeAbandonedTimeout` and a low value for `maxActive` so that you can catch unreturned connections early.

Answer (score 0):

I never use the connection pool API itself, I always wrap it in a helper.

That way, I can do this in the helper:

```
private Exception created = (0 == 1) ? new Exception() : null;
```

When I run into problems like yours, I just change one character (`0` -> `1`) to have a stack trace of who created this instance in my debugger.

Comment: Don't understand your solution. I cannot edit codebase, as I wrote. And even if could - how should this help ? What means "change one character" ?

Comment: Java doesn't track who created an object for you. If you want this, you can either try [Chronon](http://chrononsystems.com/) or change the code base. The code above is in the connection wrapper class. I change `0 == 1` to `1 == 1` and compile+deploy again. After that change, I have a stack trace in my connection wrappers that tell me who created the instance.

Comment: OK, you suggest some sort of design pattern how to implement this in new application, when creating it from the scratch. This is obviously not my case.

Comment: By the way, suppose this is not quite smart pattern as we have to rebuild application every time. The proper solution should work without rebuilding.

Comment: You can replace `(0 == 1)` with `Boolean.getBoolean()` and use a System property to switch this on and off.